# 2D shape in C++ by using the OpenGl library

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, shapes, using

I am trying to draw a shape in C++ by using the OpenGl library 
 I've written the following code , but all what I achieved is the following shape ):

[image]

but do I need to use glRotatef to get this shape :? and how can I use it ?

[image]

this is my code :)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float angle, radius, xx1, yy1;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void Transform(void);
    void circle(void);
    void shape(void);
    void init(void);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("MyShape");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Transform); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void init(void) {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
}

void Transform(void){
    void shape();
    void circle(); 
        shape();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glScalef(1.5, 1.5, 0);
    circle();   
    shape();
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void circle(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); /* draw filled red circle*/
    xx1 = 60; yy1 = 40; radius = 20;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);  
    for (angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++)
        glVertex2f(xx1 + sin(angle)*radius, yy1 + cos(angle)*radius);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}

void shape(void) {
    // Main rectangle
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  
    glVertex2i(55, 75);// left
    glVertex2i(60, 85); // top center
    glVertex2i(65, 75); // right
    glVertex2i(61, 50);// buttom right
    glVertex2i(59, 50);// buttom left
    glEnd();

    //rectangle right
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  
    glVertex2i(65, 72);// top left 
    glVertex2i(66, 69); //top right 
    glVertex2i(62, 50); // buttom right
    glVertex2i(61, 50); // buttom left
    glEnd();

    //rectangle left
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
    glVertex2i(54, 70);// top left 
    glVertex2i(55, 72); //top right 
    glVertex2i(59, 50); // buttom right
    glVertex2i(58, 50); // buttom left
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: you want filled polygon or just the polyline circumference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted your code a bit:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
int e;
float x0=60.0,y0=40.0,r=20.0,a,da=M_PI/36.0;
// move modelview to center of shape
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(-x0,-y0,-4.0*r);
// render disc
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex2f(x0,y0);
for (e=1,a=0.0;e;a+=da)
    {
    if (a>=2.0*M_PI) { e=0; a=0.0; }
    glVertex2f(x0+(r*sin(a)),y0+(r*cos(a)));
    }
glEnd();
// rotation symetry construct
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // store matrix in case you need it later or
glPushMatrix();
for (e=8,a=360.0/float(e);e>0;e--)
    {
    // render shape
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(55, 75);
    glVertex2i(60, 85);
    glVertex2i(65, 75);
    glVertex2i(61, 50);
    glVertex2i(59, 50);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(65, 72);
    glVertex2i(66, 69);
    glVertex2i(62, 50);
    glVertex2i(61, 50);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(54, 70);
    glVertex2i(55, 72);
    glVertex2i(59, 50);
    glVertex2i(58, 50);
    glEnd();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // rotate around(x0,y0)
    glTranslatef(+x0,+y0,0.0);
    glRotatef(a,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(-x0,-y0,0.0);
    }
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // restore matrix in case you need it later or
glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

So I added `for` loop and the rotation around shape center to it. Here result:

[image]

The `xs,ys` is resolution of my window for the perspective camera settings and `hdc` is my context. Also I spotted that you call `flush` after swapping buffers I would call it before.

**[Edit1] Full code**

I am using **BDS2006 C++** so the code uses **VCL** (just for creating window and events) no GLUT or anything That part you have to change to match your platform... The app is just single clean Form with single timer on it.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h> // you can ignore this
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop // you can ignore this
#include "Unit1.h" // you can ignore this
#include "gl_simple.h" // this file is in next code chunk
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init) // you can ignore this
#pragma resource "*.dfm" // you can ignore this
TForm1 *Form1; // you can ignore this its is just my window class
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw() // this renders the scene
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    int e;
    float x0=60.0,y0=40.0,r=20.0,a,da=M_PI/36.0;
    // move modelview to center of shape
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-x0,-y0,-4.0*r);
    // render disc
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(x0,y0);
    for (e=1,a=0.0;e;a+=da)
        {
        if (a>=2.0*M_PI) { e=0; a=0.0; }
        glVertex2f(x0+(r*sin(a)),y0+(r*cos(a)));
        }
    glEnd();
    // rotation symetry construct
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // store matrix in case you need it later or
    glPushMatrix();
    for (e=8,a=360.0/float(e);e>0;e--)
        {
        // render shape
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(55, 75);
        glVertex2i(60, 85);
        glVertex2i(65, 75);
        glVertex2i(61, 50);
        glVertex2i(59, 50);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(65, 72);
        glVertex2i(66, 69);
        glVertex2i(62, 50);
        glVertex2i(61, 50);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(54, 70);
        glVertex2i(55, 72);
        glVertex2i(59, 50);
        glVertex2i(58, 50);
        glEnd();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        // rotate around(x0,y0)
        glTranslatef(+x0,+y0,0.0);
        glRotatef(a,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        glTranslatef(-x0,-y0,0.0);
        }
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // restore matrix in case you need it later or
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner) // constructor of my window
    {
    gl_init(Handle);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender) // destructor of my window
    {
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender) // OnPaint event
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender) // OnTimer event
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The **gl_simple.h** is just used for creating **GL** context so you can ignore the **VAO** and **GLSL** stuff. Here the source file:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "glew.c"
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- OpenGL GL example -----------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int     xs,ys;      // screen size
HDC     hdc=NULL;   // device context
HGLRC   hrc=NULL;   // rendering context
int  gl_inicialized=0;
int  gl_init(HWND Handle);
void gl_exit();
void gl_draw();
void gl_resize(int _xs,int _ys);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- OpenGL GLSL example ---------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLint prog_id=0,    // whole program
      vert_id=0,    // vertex shader
      frag_id=0;    // fragment shader
char  glsl_log[4096];// compile/link GLSL log
int   glsl_logs=0;
void  glsl_init(char *vert,char *frag);     // create/compile/link GLSL program
void  glsl_exit();
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- OpenGL VAO example ----------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma pack(1)
//#define vao_indices
GLuint vbo[4]={-1,-1,-1,-1};
GLuint vao[4]={-1,-1,-1,-1};
const GLfloat vao_pos[]=
    {
//  x    y    z     //ix
    -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //0
    +1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //1
    +1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //2
    -1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //3
    -1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //4
    +1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //5
    +1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //6
    -1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //7

    #ifndef vao_indices
    -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //0
    +1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //1
    +1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //5
    -1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //4

    +1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //1
    +1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //2
    +1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //6
    +1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //5

    +1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //2
    -1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //3
    -1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //7
    +1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //6

    -1.0,+1.0,-1.0, //3
    -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, //0
    -1.0,-1.0,+1.0, //4
    -1.0,+1.0,+1.0, //7
    #endif
    };

const GLfloat vao_col[]=
    {
//  r   g   b    //ix
    0.0,0.0,0.0, //0
    1.0,0.0,0.0, //1
    1.0,1.0,0.0, //2
    0.0,1.0,0.0, //3
    0.0,0.0,1.0, //4
    1.0,0.0,1.0, //5
    1.0,1.0,1.0, //6
    0.0,1.0,1.0, //7

    #ifndef vao_indices
    0.0,0.0,0.0, //0
    1.0,0.0,0.0, //1
    1.0,0.0,1.0, //5
    0.0,0.0,1.0, //4

    1.0,0.0,0.0, //1
    1.0,1.0,0.0, //2
    1.0,1.0,1.0, //6
    1.0,0.0,1.0, //5

    1.0,1.0,0.0, //2
    0.0,1.0,0.0, //3
    0.0,1.0,1.0, //7
    1.0,1.0,1.0, //6

    0.0,1.0,0.0, //3
    0.0,0.0,0.0, //0
    0.0,0.0,1.0, //4
    0.0,1.0,1.0, //7
    #endif
    };

#ifndef vao_indices
const GLfloat vao_nor[]=
    {
//   nx   ny   nz   //ix
     0.0, 0.0,-1.0, //0
     0.0, 0.0,-1.0, //1
     0.0, 0.0,-1.0, //2
     0.0, 0.0,-1.0, //3

     0.0, 0.0,+1.0, //4
     0.0, 0.0,+1.0, //5
     0.0, 0.0,+1.0, //6
     0.0, 0.0,+1.0, //7

     0.0,-1.0, 0.0, //0
     0.0,-1.0, 0.0, //1
     0.0,-1.0, 0.0, //5
     0.0,-1.0, 0.0, //4

    +1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //1
    +1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //2
    +1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //6
    +1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //5

     0.0,+1.0, 0.0, //2
     0.0,+1.0, 0.0, //3
     0.0,+1.0, 0.0, //7
     0.0,+1.0, 0.0, //6

    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //3
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //0
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //4
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //7
    };
#endif

#ifdef vao_indices
const GLuint vao_ix[]=
    {
    0,1,2,3,
    4,5,6,7,
    0,1,5,4,
    1,2,6,5,
    2,3,7,6,
    3,0,4,7,
    };
#endif

#pragma pack()
void vao_init();
void vao_exit();
void vao_draw();
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- bodies: ---------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int gl_init(HWND Handle)
    {
    if (gl_inicialized) return 1;
    hdc = GetDC(Handle);            // get device context
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );      // set the pixel format for the DC
    pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    SetPixelFormat(hdc,ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd),&pfd);
    hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);            // create current rendering context
    if(hrc == NULL)
            {
            ShowMessage("Could not initialize OpenGL Rendering context !!!");
            gl_inicialized=0;
            return 0;
            }
    if(wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc) == false)
            {
            ShowMessage("Could not make current OpenGL Rendering context !!!");
            wglDeleteContext(hrc);          // destroy rendering context
            gl_inicialized=0;
            return 0;
            }
    gl_resize(1,1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                // Zbuf
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);                // vynechavaj odvratene steny
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);               // pouzivaj textury, farbu pouzivaj z textury
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);                    // priehladnost
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                // gourard shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   // background color
    gl_inicialized=1;
    glewInit();
    return 1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_exit()
    {
    if (!gl_inicialized) return;
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);     // release current rendering context
    wglDeleteContext(hrc);          // destroy rendering context
    gl_inicialized=0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_resize(int _xs,int _ys)
    {
    xs=_xs;
    ys=_ys;
    if (xs<=0) xs = 1;                  // Prevent a divide by zero
    if (ys<=0) ys = 1;
    if (!gl_inicialized) return;
    glViewport(0,0,xs,ys);              // Set Viewport to window dimensions
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);        // operacie s projekcnou maticou
    glLoadIdentity();                   // jednotkova matica projekcie
    gluPerspective(30,float(xs)/float(ys),0.1,100.0); // matica=perspektiva,120 stupnov premieta z viewsize do 0.1
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);           // operacie s texturovou maticou
    glLoadIdentity();                   // jednotkova matica textury
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);         // operacie s modelovou maticou
    glLoadIdentity();                   // jednotkova matica modelu (objektu)
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glsl_init(char *vert,char *frag)
    {
    const int _size=1024;
    GLint status,siz=0,i;
    const char * VS = vert;
    const char * FS = frag;
    glsl_logs=0;
    if (prog_id<=0) prog_id=glCreateProgram();

    if (vert_id<=0) vert_id=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); else glDetachShader(prog_id,vert_id);
    if (vert)
        {
        glShaderSource(vert_id, 1, &VS,NULL);
        glCompileShader(vert_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,vert_id);
        glGetShaderiv(vert_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        const char t[]="[Vertex]\r\n"; for (i=0;t[i];i++) { glsl_log[glsl_logs]=t[i]; glsl_logs++; }
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vert_id,_size,&siz,glsl_log+glsl_logs);
        glsl_logs+=siz;
        }
    if (frag_id<=0) frag_id=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); else glDetachShader(prog_id,frag_id);
    if (frag)
        {
        glShaderSource(frag_id, 1, &FS,NULL);
        glCompileShader(frag_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,frag_id);
        glGetShaderiv(frag_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        const char t[]="[Fragment]\r\n"; for (i=0;t[i];i++) { glsl_log[glsl_logs]=t[i]; glsl_logs++; }
        glGetShaderInfoLog(frag_id,_size,&siz,glsl_log+glsl_logs);
        glsl_logs+=siz;
        }

    glLinkProgram(prog_id);
    glGetProgramiv(prog_id,GL_LINK_STATUS,&status);
    const char t[]="[Program]\r\n"; for (i=0;t[i];i++) { glsl_log[glsl_logs]=t[i]; glsl_logs++; }
    glGetShaderInfoLog(prog_id,_size,&siz,glsl_log+glsl_logs);
    glsl_logs+=siz;

    glReleaseShaderCompiler();
    glsl_log[glsl_logs]=0;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glsl_exit()
    {
    glUseProgram(0);
    if (vert_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,vert_id); glDeleteShader(vert_id); }
    if (frag_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,frag_id); glDeleteShader(frag_id); }
    if (prog_id>0) {                                  glDeleteShader(prog_id); }
    glsl_log[0]=0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_init()
    {
    GLuint i;
    glGenVertexArrays(4,vao);
    glGenBuffers(4,vbo);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    i=0; // vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_pos),vao_pos,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    i=1; // indices
    #ifdef vao_indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_ix),vao_ix,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,4,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    #endif
    i=2; // normal
    #ifndef vao_indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_nor),vao_nor,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    #endif
    i=3; // color
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_col),vao_col,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_exit()
    {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(4,vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(4,vbo);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_draw()
    {
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    #ifndef vao_indices
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,sizeof(vao_pos)/sizeof(GLfloat));                       // QUADS ... no indices
    #endif
    #ifdef vao_indices
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,sizeof(vao_idx)/sizeof(GLuint),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);  // indices (choose just one line not both !!!)
    #endif
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**btw** this file is taken from:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

The `M_PI=3.1415926535897932384626433832795` is constant defined in

```
#include <math.h>
```

Which you should have already included as you are using `sin,cos` functions from it.

The **GLEW.c** is wrangler for OpenGL extensions and as you using just **OpenGL 1.0** you do not need it ... but of coarse once you remove the include you need to delete also all **VAO/VBO** and **GLSL** stuff from this file (which is not used anyway)

Comment: Thank you sho Much ,
What about (M_PI)??

Comment: Can you share your full code please ?
because I got a lot of errors :(

Comment: @user3554225 `M_PI=3.1415926535897932384626433832795` is in `#include <math.h>` Yes I can share full code but I am using BDS2006 VCL so I doubt it would help you. What kind of errors ? the rendering is fully compilable ... the only thing you need to change is `xs,ys,hdc`  and `SwapBuffers(hdc);` for your GLUT counterparts.

Comment: @user3554225 added edit1  with the full code but as I mentioned it is VCL window so you need to change the events to GLUT counterparts and instead `Form1` use your OpenGL window properties...

Comment: I couldn't get through this :(
Do you have 10 min to check this on my pc ?
if not , do you know anyone can ? even for paid tutorial

Comment: @user3554225 What errors you got? and on which lines ?

Comment: TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)

Comment: @user3554225 so you did just copy paste without removing VCL stuff ... no wander it is not working the esiest for you would use your code and put the rendering code from my first code chunk into your `Transform` function. `xs=400, ys=300, M_PI=3.1415926` and instead of `SwapBuffers(hdc);` use `glutSwapBuffers();` that should work ...

Comment: Thank you So much << big harts for you > :)